# Results from MYSQL database based, not one, but on results from a few tables

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

So here I am and need to see some results from a MYSQL database based not on one but on results from a few tables.

TABLE DESCRIPTION:

```
Metaexplanation:

Tablename

Row1,Row2,Row3....Row(N)

Tables:

---------------
|table toy  |
------------------------------ 
|toy_id | name | description  |
------------------------------


--------------------
|table owned_toy  |
----------------------------
| owner  | toy_id          |
----------------------------


--------------------
|table toy_expansions |
-------------------------------
| expansion | toy_id          |
-------------------------------
```

I created a query to identify toys with no owner assigned

```
SELECT DISTINCT * from toy WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ownedtoy WHERE owned_toy.toy_id = toy.id);
```

That worked and I was able to identify things that had no owner.

Now to make things more interesting I am trying to find out a way to discover how many expansions exist for each of the toys that I have identified in the query above.

I can count the total number of expansions to the toys using:

```
Select COUNT(expansion) from toy_expansions;
```

However what I need is to see the total number of expansions for each DISTINCT toy that does not yet have an owner, and it needs to be sorted so that I see the results from the first query combined with a column saying "number of Expansions" that lists the number of expansions for each toy identified to have no owner

I would like to be able to adding the results by combining the original query with a statement like this:

```
Select COUNT(expansion) as "Number of expansions" from toy_expansions
```

Also just to make it a little more difficult I would like to be able to execute it in one single query without creating extra tables etc. i.e. without making any changes to the db itself.

Any ideas ?

Comment: On the table `toy_expansions` what does the column `id` and `expansions` hold? Which one identifies the toy id?

Comment: Made a minor clarification to tables makes sense now ?

Comment: Look @Joe Stefanelli's answer, that should do just fine.

Comment: LOL folks are commenting/upvoting the comment that points to my answer, but not upvoting [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845140/results-from-mysql-database-based-not-one-but-on-results-from-a-few-tables/6845286#6845286) itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.name, COUNT(te.expansion) AS NumberOfExpansions
    FROM toy t
        LEFT JOIN toy_expansions te
            ON t.id = te.toy_id
        LEFT JOIN owned_toy ot
            ON t.id = ot.toy_id
    WHERE ot.toy_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY t.name
```

Comment: ...oops, my query is almost the same